# Display all child records of a parent in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagridview, ado.net

I am new to .NET, and I don't really understand how it works. I have this project I have to do and I'm asked to display all parent records, and when I select a parent record there should be displayed all its children. So far I managed to display all the parent records, using a DataGridView.

```
private void display_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dg.DataSource = data_set.Tables[0];
        }
```

The following code works but it displays all the records from the child. I know that I should compare somehow the primary key from the parent with the foreign key from the child and display from the child only those who are equal with the PK from the parent, but I don't know how to write it.

```
private void dg_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            dg2.DataSource = data_set.Tables[1];

        }
```

The code for creating the relation

```
 DataColumn parentColumn = data_set.Tables["Airline"].Columns["airline_id"];
                DataColumn childColumn = data_set.Tables["Plane"].Columns["airline_id"];

                rel_pln_air = new DataRelation("fk_pln_air", parentColumn, childColumn);
                data_set.Relations.Add(rel_pln_air);
```

The code for binding:

```
parentBindingSource.DataSource = data_set;
            parentBindingSource.DataMember = "Airline";
            childBindingSource.DataSource = parentBindingSource;
            childBindingSource.DataMember = "Plane";
```

Comment: Are you sure you are doing what you mean to do?   Seems odd to me to create a relationship on airline_id to plane_id.

Comment: Thanks I missed that. And how exactly helps me this relation to what I am trying to do ?

Comment: Can anyone help me please. I don't want code just some tips on how I could do this

Answer (score 0):

You must define mster-details relation between `Tables[1]` and `Tables[2]` in your dataset. Then you must set the `DataSource` of your child `DataGridView` to that relation.

[Walkthrough: Creating a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y8c0cxey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
is the detailed explanation of your problem.

**UPDATE**

The `airline_id` can't be related to the `plane_id`. I thing you have the `airline_id` in you `plane` table to which you must reference.

Comment: I have changed the question, I tried to define a relation but I don't understand why it doesn't work. I checked in the database and all child reffer to a parent record

Comment: Have you look at the article?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have managed to create the relation between the 2 tables. But now I don't understand the part with the binding..

Comment: I have added the code for binding, it compiles, but I still don't get it how I could use this stuff to display all the childs of a parent record

Answer (score 0):

Link the same column as I stated in the comment
Use GetChildRows to walk the relationship

[DataRow.GetChildRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.getchildrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)