# SQL Database Relationships & VB.Net Application

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I know these questions have been asked and answered multiple times all over these forums and the internet but I am struggling to wrap my head around it.  I am having trouble understanding exactly how the relationships work with Primary and foreign keys in an SQL Database.  Say I have a Table Called "Employees" with the Primary key named "employeeID" then another table name "Addresses" with the Primary key named "addressID" I would create a Foreign key in the "Addresses" table called "employeeID" then create the relationship between the Employees table and the Addresses table correct?

I have a database that has Employees, Addresses, Emergency Contacts etc... where from what I have read and understood from various sources is created correctly.  So in my application vb.net using Azure SQL DB I am trying to display in a datagridview say the employees and their addresses. It is obvious that a datagridview can only display information from one table at a time so I tried to create a new dataset that would gather the information from the two tables and the display it as one in the gatagrid view.  When the datagrid view displays this information it is all mixed up and the relationships are not being honored.  For each entry in the employee table it lists each entry for each person three times in the address table. [image]

Here is a copy of the code for the Dataset I am using:

```
   Dim connectionstring As String = My.Settings.MacroQualityConnectionString
    Dim sqlemp As String = "SELECT * FROM Employee_Names, Addresses"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlemp, connection)
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(dsemployees, "Employee_Names")
    connection.Close()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dsemployees.Tables(0)
```

I know it probably isn't correct but I am not sure how to make the application honor the relationships in the database?  Eventually I need to be able to gather information from multiple tables to be correctly displayed in a datagridview but unfortunately my SQL skills are quite weak among most of my other skills!  Maybe most of my issue is back at the design and set up of my DB?  Any input is greatly appreciated everyone as I have been struggling with this for a few weeks now! :(

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Why are you using Cross Join in Select Statement rather then inner join ???????

Comment: I flagged this question as it's better off in another place as it's asking about relationships in a server.

Comment: most of those tables seem like they ought to be columns on the Emp table.  An employee has an address, phone etc so columns are sort of like properties.  Where a PK/FK relationship might come in is `Department` - and Emp belongs to a Dept and a Dept can have many emps.  Then the Emp would have a FK to the Dept table (not the other way round)

Comment: I'm not sure, I wasn't able to get very far with inner join. Should it be something more like: "SELECT * FROM employees join addresses on employee.id = address.id" or something?

Comment: okay so I should have the employees addresses in the same table?  I was trying to eliminate redundancy as the addresses table will encompass employees, third party companies etc...

Comment: @KyleMoffat : yes use inner join instead join

Comment: how many employees live at the location of 3rd party vendors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly define the relationship in the query with a `JOIN` clause.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee_Names
INNER JOIN Addresses
  ON Employee_Names.employeeID = Addresses.employeeID
```

This tells the query to explicitly follow that key relationship (which it might be smart enough to figure out on its own for simple relationships, depending on the RDBMS, but being explicit makes the code more clear).

What this produces *is* "one table" in the sense that the results are one set of records.  However, consider logically what that would mean if any given record in the `Employee_Names` table has more than one associated record in the `Addresses` table.  Flattening them into a single table of results like this would mean that there would be duplicate `Employee_Names` records.

Such is the nature of tabular data.  If a single grid is displaying two dimensions of data, it's going to have to flatten them, resulting in some repeated data.

Essentially you need to ask yourself exactly what a "record" in the `DataGridView` should represent.  Currently it represents a unique combination of `Employee_Names` and `Addresses`.  Regardless of repeats, it's going to show every combination.

If, instead, you want each record to represent a unique `Employee_Names` record then you wouldn't want to perform the `JOIN` in the query quite like that.  Instead, you'd be looking to use that foreign key relationship to indicate parent/child records and bind the `DataGridView` to multiple tables (instead of a single table of results from the query).

I don't have much experience with the tooling for that, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895665/display-all-child-records-of-a-parent-in-datagridview) seems like a reasonable place to start.  The idea is that the `DataGridView` would show records from the `Employee_Names` table, and clicking an expandable area of any given record would then show associated records from the `Addresses` table in a sub-grid.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so Much!! I definitely need to touch my SQL skills.